# You must initialize OneSignal before modifying tags!Moving this operation to a pending task queue. Este error y otros dos me salen!

Tags: java, android-studio, onesignal, logcat

**Estos son todos los errores que me tira**

```
E/OneSignal: You must initialize OneSignal before modifying tags!Moving this operation to a pending task queue.
```

**El segundo error es este**

```
E/OneSignal: Unknown error getting FCM Token java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please set your project ID. A valid Firebase project ID is required to communicate with Firebase server APIs: It identifies your project with Google.
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play services-basement@@17.1.1:8)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.0:52)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.0:2)
    at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorFCM.getToken(PushRegistratorFCM.java:51)
    at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.attemptRegistration(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:97)
    at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.access$100(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:37)
    at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle$1.run(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:84)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

**El tercer error es este**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.themescoder.androidecommerce, PID: 6424
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1333)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:916)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:458)
    at com.themescoder.androidecommerce.network.APIClient.getInstance(APIClient.java:71)
    at com.themescoder.androidecommerce.network.StartAppRequests.RequestAppSetting(StartAppRequests.java:193)
    at com.themescoder.androidecommerce.network.StartAppRequests.StartRequests(StartAppRequests.java:55)
    at com.themescoder.androidecommerce.activities.SplashScreen$MyTask.doInBackground(SplashScreen.java:191)
    at com.themescoder.androidecommerce.activities.SplashScreen$MyTask.doInBackground(SplashScreen.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

He intentado mirar la clave del google-service.json y no entiendo que toca hacer, ademas investigue en documentos en ingles pero no encuentro soluciones, si alguien conoce las posibles soluciones les agradeceria

Comment: no deberias agregar el codigo que produce este error?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Fijate que no te falta inicializar la libreria en MainActivity.